# Show only some of HtmlElements in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control, visibility

I try to hide all elements of a webbrowser control and show only some of them. As hiding all the elements takes time, I used the following code in which I hide the body element and then show my desired elements

```
 IHTMLElement2 bodyDom = webBrowser1.Document.Body.DomElement as IHTMLElement2;
 bodyDom.runtimeStyle.visibility = "hidden";
 foreach (var item in elementsToShow)
 {
     IHTMLElement2 dom = item.DomElement as IHTMLElement2;           
     dom.runtimeStyle.visibility = "visible";    
 }
```

This code works for most websites, but in some websites when the body elements is hidden, changing the `visiblity` of the elements doesn't work! (they are still hidden, why it may happens?).

In general, what the solution (a robust) do you offer for this task?

Comment: because if parent container element is hidden then child elements will also be hidden

Comment: @EhsanSajjad its true when the child visibility is set to `inherit` but I set their visibility to `visible` and it works most of the time, just it doesn't work in a Persian website (www.tabnak.ir)